# Problem on triangle similarity.

Tags: geometry

*PQRS* is a square. The bisector of angle SQR meets *PR* and *SR* at *T* and *V* respectively. **Prove that:** `QV*TR = QT*SV`

[image]

Comment: Every angle is trivial to find. Why not use brute force?

Comment: @Karolis Juodelė what do you mean by brute force?

Comment: I mean to find the length of every line segment, assuming $PQ = a$. You'll only need a tiny little bit of trigonometry.

Comment: Oh wait, QTR is similar to SVQ (just write down the angles). The property follows.

Comment: oh didn't see that, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** As a preliminary step, do some **angle-chasing**. We can even do it mindlessly, without plan. Just fill in **all** the angles. The only fact we will need is that the angles of a triangle add up to $180^\circ$.

As a start, note that $\angle RQS=45^\circ$, so $\angle VQS=\angle VQR=22.5^\circ$. But $\angle QSV=45^\circ$, so $\angle SVQ=180^\circ-(22.5^\circ+45^\circ)=112.5^\circ$.  You may find things less messy if you let $22.5^\circ=a$. Then the angles of $\triangle QSV$ are $a$, $2a$, and $5a$.

Keep filling in angles. When you are finished, or earlier, look for similar triangles. You will notice that $\triangle QSV$ has the same angles as $\triangle QRT$. So these two triangles are **similar**.

Your desired equality is a direct consequence of this similarity. It comes more naturally as $\frac{SV}{QV}=\frac{TR}{QR}$. Or perhaps note that $SV$ and $TR$ are *corresponding sides* of our two similar triangles, as are $QV$ and $QT$, so 
$\frac{SV}{TR}=\frac{QV}{QT}$.